# Installed i18next now i get TypeError: (0, _native.createNavigatorFactory) is not a function

Tags: json, react-native

I am working with a react native project. It was working fine until i ran: npm install react-i18next i18next --save. I wanted to add this for the translations, as i have done for other projects.

## Now i get the following errors:

```
ERROR  TypeError: (0, _native.createNavigatorFactory) is not a function. (In '(0, _native.createNavigatorFactory)(StackNavigator)', '(0, _native.createNavigatorFactory)' is undefined)
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

## Package.json:

```
 },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.10.4",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.7.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "i18next": "^23.2.11",
    "mobx": "^5.15.7",
    "mobx-persist": "^0.4.1",
    "mobx-react": "^6.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.5",
    "react-native-actions-sheet": "^0.3.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-static-safe-area-insets": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-wheel-pick": "^1.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.9.2",
    "serializr": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.5.1",
    "babel-preset-mobx": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
```

- I have tried cleaning cache.
- I tried re-installing "@react-navigation/native.
- Tried killing all node processes.
- Tried removing the new packages installed from the dependencies list.